# Avoid class duplications while importing global SCSS

Tags: reactjs, sass, vite

I am building a new ReactJS project with Vite and using scss for stying. I have colors, fonts, etc. classes that are forwarded from one _index.scss file.

```
@forward 'colors';
@forward 'constants';
@forward 'typography';
@forward 'alignment';
@forward 'common';
```

I need to use these classes for each component's individual scss. When I use @use to import that index class. Importing like this and my project works properly.

```
@use '/src/styles';
```

However, I see duplicated classes on developer tools for each component that is used on the page.

I want to use these classes from every other scss file but don't want them to duplicate. Looking for a while but I couldn't find a proper solution.

I have tried to use import and also tried to use configure vite to import certain files to avoid this but it is still duplicated. I also added it into app.js but it didn't work. I researched and couldn't find a well-explained solution.

Thanks

Comment: Are you confident/certain that the duplication is actually in the CSS sent to the browser?  Is it possible you're only seeing duplication in the SCSS being mapped back from the sourcemaps in the dev tools?

Comment: I have tried to build application and run it with preview command in vite. Even there I am seeing the same duplicates. I dont think its related with dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your partials include non-[placeholder selectors](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors/), then all of these selectors will be included in the files where you import (use/forward) them. So for example if you have two components, each of them importing its own style file, which in turn imports the partials: you get the duplicate selectors.

If you want to have global classes, then you should only import them once, in your entry component file. And if you also need to import variables, mixins, functions, etc, you should use separate partials.

For example:

```
src/
└── styles/
    ├── non-selectors/
    │   ├── _variables.scss
    │   ├── _mixins.scss
    │   └── index.scss
    ├── global-selectors/
    │   ├── _common.scss
    │   ├── _typography.scss
    │   └── index.js
    └── App.jsx
```

On the index style files:

```scss
// src/styles/non-selectors/index.scss

@forward 'variables';
@forward 'mixins';
```

```scss
// src/styles/global-selectors/index.scss

@use 'common';
@use 'typography';
```

On your entry component file:

```js
// App.jsx

import "./styles/global-selectors/index.scss";
    
const App = () => {
  // ...
};

export default App;
```

And on any component needed the variables, mixins, etc:

```scss
// MyComponent/styles.scss

@use '/src/styles/non-selectors';
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. This approach works in general but I still have one issue. Is there a way to extend global classes from component classes because even if I import them in App.jsx they cannot be extendable from component classes?

Comment: Ok, that's what I was asking. I have global classes that I use in JSX files but I also used the @extend keyword on component classes to extend these classes. It seems with that approach I must segregate them otherwise they will duplicate. I think mixins or placeholder selectors can fix my issue but there might be some duplications.

Comment: @ErtuğrulŞentürk Sorry, I deleted my comment because what I was saying was not completely true. You can use placeholder selectors to extend shared classes without duplication, but it will not truly extend them and act more like mixins.

Comment: I am little confused. For example If I create a regular or placeholder under global-selectors. I still need to create a mixin or placeholder class under non-selectors to use them with @extend keyword in seperate files. If I need it on both places. Should I have to duplicate them?

Comment: @ErtuğrulŞentürk you just have to create the placeholder/mixin under non-selectors and you can use it in any file as long as it's imported with `@use`, no need to duplicate the code.